# Initialize the arrays inside an array of char* using a loop

Tags: c

I need to create an array of strings, each representing a card of the Spanish deck:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *type[4]= {"copas", "basto", "espada", "oro"};
    char *number[10]= {"Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Siete", "Diez", "Once", "Doce"};
    char *deck[40];
    int deckIndex= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          char card[100] = "";
          strcat(card, number[j]);
          strcat(card, " de ");
          strcat(card, type[i]);
          strcat(card, "\n");
          deck[deckIndex]= card;
          deckIndex++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", deck[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, all entries of deck[] point to the same string. As a result, "Doce de oro" is printed 40 times. I don't understand why this happens, but I've theorized it's because card[] is being reinitialized in the same memory direction, and overrides what was already written there in the previous iteration. If I'm right, I would have to declare every array separately, but I have no idea how to do that without writing 40 different arrays.

Tldr:
¿Why do all entries of deck[] point to the same location?
¿How do I fix it?

(Btw suggestions for a better title are appreciated)

Comment: "*all entries of deck[] point to the same string*". It's worse than that. `card` only exists for one iteration of the loop. It becomes invalid after the end of each iteration. So accessing it outside the iteration and outside the loop results in Undefined Behaviour. Use `strdup` to make a dynamic copy. Don't forget to `free` the memory.

Comment: FYI you can use sprintf to construct your card string in one simple statement rather than making a sequence of  strcat calls. Also, you probably do not want to append newline to the card.

Comment: char deck[40][100] declares 40 strings of 100 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, memory on the stack is allocated in terms of Scopes. So yes, your theory is right. You are rewriting on the same location.

To fix your program, there are **two possible** solutions I can think of.

- You can use **Multidimensional Arrays**.
- Or you can **allocate memory in heap** using `malloc` (but make sure to free it once you are done with it)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, in the `deck[deckIndex]= card;` line, you are assigning the same pointer<sup>1</sup> to each of your `deck` elements – and, worse, a pointer to a variable (the `card` array) that is no longer valid when the initial nested `for` loop goes out of scope.

To fix this, you can make copies of the `card` string, using [the strdup function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), and assign the addresses of those copies to the `deck` elements. Further, as also mentioned in the comments, you can simplify the construction of the `card` string using a *single* call to [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), rather than using multiple `strcat` calls.

Here's how you might do that:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* type[4] = { "copas", "basto", "espada", "oro" };
    char* number[10] = { "Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Siete", "Diez", "Once", "Doce" };
    char* deck[40];
    int deckIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            char card[100] = "";
            sprintf(card, "%s de %s", number[j], type[i]);
            deck[deckIndex] = strdup(card);
            deckIndex++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", deck[i]);
    }

    // When you're done, be sure to free the allocated memory:
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        free(deck[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler does not support the `strdup` function (most do, and it is part of the ISO C Standard from C23), writing your own is very simple:

```c
char* strdup(const char *src)
{
    char* result = malloc(strlen(src) + 1); // Add one to make room for the nul terminator
    if (result) strcpy(result, src);
    return result;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, formally, a new `card` array is born on each iteration of the inner `for` loop, but it would be a very inefficient compiler that chose to do that, rather than simply re-using the same memory – which is clearly what is happening in your case.